# Conformal map on the unit circle

Tags: conformal-geometry

I would like to find a conformal map from the unit circle to the unit circle so that point(a,0) is mapped onto (0,0), while every point on the circumference is mapped onto itself.

Is there an easy way to get the analytical expression of such a map?

Thank you

Comment: $f(z)=\frac {z-a} {1-az}$. For all conformal maps of the unit disk, look at Rudin's RCA.